# Persistence in GJR-GARCH (asymmetric GARCH)

Tags: garch, volatility-forecasting

Consider the standard GARCH model:

$$ \sigma^2_t = \omega + \alpha\varepsilon^2_{t-1} + \beta\sigma^2_{t-1}.$$

The so-called persistence parameter is defined as the sum $\alpha+\beta$.

Now consider the GJR-GARCH model by Glosten et al. (1993):

$$ \sigma^2_t = \omega + (\alpha+\gamma \mathbb{I}_{t-1})\varepsilon^2_{t-1} + \beta\sigma^2_{t-1} $$

where $\mathbb{I}_{t-1}$ is the indicator function:

$\mathbb{I}_{t-1}(\varepsilon_{t-1})=\varepsilon_{t-1}$ for $\varepsilon_{t-1}>0$ and 
 
$\mathbb{I}_{t-1}(\varepsilon_{t-1})=0$ otherwise.

**Question:** What is the persistence parameter in the GJR-GARCH model? Could someone provide some references where this is explained?

My guess is that the persistence parameter equals $\alpha+\gamma/2+\beta$, but I am not sure. The guess is based on the material in [V-Lab](http://vlab.stern.nyu.edu/doc/3?topic=mdls) and the similarities between the standard GARCH and the GJR-GARCH model.

**References**

- Glosten, L. R., R. Jagannathan, and D. E. Runkle, 1993. On The Relation between The Expected Value and The Volatility of Nominal Excess Return on stocks. Journal of Finance 48: 1779-1801.
- [V-Lab](http://vlab.stern.nyu.edu/doc/3?topic=mdls)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found an answer in the ["vignette"](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rugarch/vignettes/Introduction_to_the_rugarch_package.pdf) to the "rugarch" package in R. Here is a quote from pages 7-8 (*emphasis is mine*):

> Because of the presence of the indicator function, the persistence of
>   the model now crucially depends on the **asymmetry** of the conditional
>   distribution used. The persistence of the model $\hat P$ is,
>
> $$ \hat P = \sum_{j=1}^q \alpha_j + \sum_{j=1}^p \beta_j + \sum_{j=1}^q \gamma_j\kappa $$
>
> where $\kappa$ is the expected value of the standardized residuals
>   $z_t$ below zero (effectively the probability of being below zero),
>
> $$ \kappa = \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{I}_{t-j} z_{t-j}^2) = \int_{-\infty}^0 f(z,1,0,\dotsc) dz $$
>
> where $f$ is the standardized conditional density with any additional
>   skew and shape parameters $(\dotsc)$. In the case of **symmetric**
>   distributions the value of $\kappa$ is simply equal to 0.5.

Comment: Are the negative residuals to be squared, because the text doesn't indicate that. I suppose it should say squared negative standardized residuals.

Comment: @Statwonk, what context exactly does your question refer to? Negative residuals to be squared where, in which equation or statement?