# In a GJR model, is there any interpretation attributed to half of the asymmetry parameter?

Tags: time-series, interpretation, garch, volatility-forecasting

I'm reading [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/24812849?seq=1) by Abosedra et. al (2006), where they study the volatility of US natural gas prices.

They report the estimation from a AR(1)-GARCH(1,1) model and a AR(1)-GJR-GARCH(1,1) model as in the image below.

Why do they also report $ \alpha+ \beta + \frac12 \lambda $? And how does this turn out to be exactly the same as $ \alpha + \beta $ in the AR(1)-GARCH(1,1) model?

*Note:* $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ here are the ARCH, GARCH and Asymmetry (GJR model) parameters respectively. The equation(s) estimated is given below the table, if necessary.

[image]

Estimated equation(s):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if half the asymmetry parameter has any useful interpretation **on its own**, but it does **in the context of** $\alpha+\beta+\frac{1}{2}\lambda$. Judging from the table you have included, the authors probably want to measure persistence in volatility. As is clarified in the thread ["Persistence in GJR-GARCH (asymmetric GARCH)"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/115925), the **persistence** of GJR-GARCH(1,1) is $$\alpha+\beta+\frac{1}{2}\lambda$$ if the distribution of standardized innovations is symmetric. The persistence of vanilla GARCH(1,1) is $$\alpha+\beta.$$ You have both of these in the table.

Comment: Is there any significance to the fact that the persistence measures for both the models are exactly the same?

Comment: @WorldGov, this is an interesting finding. For those who care directly about persistence, this shows its measurement is robust to model choice between vanilla GARCH and GJR-GARCH. This holds for this specific time series but not necessarily in general.