# Long-Run Variance LRV for TGARCH and GJR-GARCH

Tags: garch, volatility

As LRV calculation from GARCH parameters is on annual basis:

$$ LRV = \frac{\omega}{1 - \alpha - \beta} \cdot 252 $$

I wonder if it's not a composition of unconditional variance divided by the model persistence?

As the spec of TGARCH is based simply on $\sigma$ and not on $\sigma^2$, what could be the LRV knowing that its persistence?

My potential answer:
$$ LRV = \bigg(\frac{\omega}{1- \beta - \alpha/\sqrt{2 \pi} - \theta/\sqrt{2 \pi}}\bigg)^2 \cdot 252 $$

And for GJR-GARCH what would it be?

My potential answer:
$$ LRV = \frac{\omega}{1 - ( \alpha + \theta/2 + \beta)} \cdot 252 $$

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I made some formatting corrections. Please see if I might have missed a parenthesis or anything.

Comment: @Azertux0, where do you got these equations from?

Comment: In my opinion, it is strange to annualize volatility using the square root of time rule when dealing with a model that explicitly assumes that returns are not iid. Just from a theoretical point of view, this seems to be a bit odd but I am pretty sure that this is general practice.

Comment: RichardHardy, thank you

@Lars, the GARCH LRV equation comes from my former courses on the subject. Unfortunately, I don't have any detail of how it's obtained. The TGARCH and GJR LRV are just hypothesis.

Comment: The sqrt of time comes from my comprehension of the TGARCH model as follows: We do actually try to estimate the volatility through σ(t) and not variance σ^2(t) and that the parameters are to the power of 1 by opposition to GARCH :
σ(t)= Ω + αϵ(t-1) * (1 if (ϵ(t-1) > 0) else 0)  + Θϵ(t-1) * (1 if (ϵ(t-1) < 0) else 0) + βσ(t−1)

Comment: You just calculate $E(\sigma_t^2)\cdot252$ for different models. The expressions seem to be correct.

Comment: @Lars, That's tricky and it does greatly the job, thanks !

Comment: Related: ["Persistence in GJR-GARCH (asymmetric GARCH)"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/115925).

Comment: @Azertux0 I summarized my thoughts in an answer. Also, take a look at the link provided by Richard Hardy. He provides a very good explanation why the persistence of the GJR-GARCH model is $\frac{\omega}{1-\alpha-\frac{\theta}{2}-\beta}$. For this to hold, you need the assumption of a symmetric distribution of the error term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, the (annualized) long run variance can be calculated as
$$
LRV=E(\sigma_t^2) \cdot 252
$$
or in terms of standard deviations as
$$
LRV=\sqrt{E(\sigma_t^2)}\sqrt{252}
$$
assuming that there are $252$ trading days within a year and that you estimate your model on daily returns. Now, depending on your model, the expression for $E(\sigma_t^2)$ differs.

For instance, for the GARCH(1,1) you have:
$$
E(\sigma_t)^2=\frac{\omega}{1-\alpha-\beta}
$$
For the GJR-GARCH(1,1) you get
$$
E(\sigma_t^2)=\frac{\omega}{1-\alpha-\frac{\theta}2{-\beta}}
$$
if you assume a symmetric distribution for the error term.